# jquery click event with reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering why this code:

```
$('.button').click(window.location.reload)
```

triggers illegal invocation

And this code :

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    window.location.reload()
})
```

works fine.

I don't know the difference and why only the latter works?

Comment: I assume this is because .click() sends an optional parameter (event object) that is misinterpreted (and discarded in the second option)

Comment: Where specifically is the error thrown?  From within jQuery, or from within `reload()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reload()` references `this`. In the working example, `this` points to `window.location`. In the shorter version you tried, `this` points to `window`.

This will work:

```
$('.button').click(window.location.reload.bind(window.location));
```

Here, `window.location` is bound to serve as `reload()`s context.

Comment: We just post almost same time! duplicate of my answer as well!

Comment: If you had posted earlier, I'd have removed my duplicate.